# How to hide characters using for loops, respectively?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I want to basically hide characters following three constant dots (...), the pattern goes like this:

---

Inputs a phrase from the user and outputs the phrase followed by three dots (...), then the phrase minus one character followed by three dots (...), then the phrase minus two characters followed by the dots, and so on until only one dot is left.

**Note: This has to be done using nested for loops only**

Sample input

```
 1
 disappear
```

Expected output:

```
 disappear...
 disappea...
 disappe...
 disapp...
 disap...
 disa...
 dis...
 di...
 d...
 ...
 ..
 .
```

This is my attempt:

**Problem**: I am unable to make it so the phrase decreases each time (minus 1 each time)

I tried using the charAt(); method, but it wouldn't work, I am sure that you would need a for loop separate for each of the dots or a whole set of dots, in this case.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Dissappear{
public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option = keyboard.nextInt();
    String phrase = keyboard.next();
        if (option == 1){
            for (int x = 0; x <= phrase.length(); x++){
                    System.out.print(phrase + "...");
                for (int y = 0; y <= phrase.length(); y++){
                    char n = phrase.charAt(y);
                    System.out.print(n+"...");
                }
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: You can use Recursion ?

Comment: Nope I cant use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it to work:

```
public class Disappear {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String word = "disappear";
        int originalLength = word.length();

        for(int i = 0; i < originalLength; i++) {
            System.out.println(word.substring(0, originalLength - i) + "...");
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3 - i; j++) {
                System.out.print(".");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Without substring:

```
public class Disappear {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String word = "disappear";
        int originalLength = word.length();

        for(int i = 0; i < originalLength; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < originalLength - i; j++) {
                System.out.print(word.charAt(j));
            }

            System.out.println("...");
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3 - i; j++) {
                System.out.print(".");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cant use "while"

Comment: I've revised my post to meet your specifications @HussainOmer

Comment: Is there also a way without the substring method?

Comment: @HussainOmer yes, I've added a method for that in my original answer

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific enough, what I meant was that I am not allowed to use built-in methods of java like word split, substring...etc. only for loops.

Comment: @HussainOmer can you use charAt?

Comment: I am trying to use the charAt method to see if it works

Comment: Yes definitely u can use it

Comment: Why does it print numbers instead of letters?

Comment: @HussainOmer Is the second code I provided outputting numbers instead of letters?

Comment: Yes the "without substring" code, in the first part with just outputting the phrase instead of trailing dots, it just ouputs numbers instead of letters

Comment: @HussainOmer That is really strange... It doesn't do that on any runtime machine I have tried

Comment: @HussainOmer I put an interactive example on repl.it: https://repl.it/@JaeheonShim/DisappearExample

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with StringBuilder:

```
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(str);

    System.out.println(str + "...");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1);
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString() + "...");
        if (i == length - 1) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                for (int k = j; k < 2; k++) {
                    System.out.print(".");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok! Nested `for` loops.  But the outer one is only included to meet the requirement.  Probably not in the spirit of the assignment though.  Just keep decrementing `k` until it is zero and then latch it there until the `StringBuilder` length is `0` and the inner loop terminates.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("disappear...");
for (;;) {
    for (int k = sb.length() - 4; sb.length() > 0;) {
        System.out.println(sb);
        sb.delete(k, k + 1);
        k = k > 0 ? --k : 0;
    }
    break;
}
```